# How do I scale a div and then reverse the transform all in the same click using css and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transform

I am working on a memory game. When the player matches two cards, after clicking on the 2nd card of the matched pair, both cards animate by scaling up 130% while completing a full 360% rotation in 500 milliseconds. What I'd like the animation to do at that point is pause for 1 second and then reverse itself (scale down to 100% and rotate -360% in another 500 milliseconds. I can't seem to find the right callback function or use of keyframes or other alternative to create a smooth transform effect through the whole process.

Because of cross-browser compatibility issues, I've been asked to use jQuery instead of relying solely on css. I've included my code for the project below. Right now, I have minimal html, some css and some javascript. I also use jQuery. Please, if anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be sincerely grateful. I'm still new to all code languages so simple explanations are preferred.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

body {
    background: linear-gradient(#2C1760, #D2D1DD);
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
}
div#symbols{
    margin:auto;
    width:1600px;
    display:none;
}

div#memory_board{
    background: linear-gradient(#D4BFF5, #8743DC);
    border:#999 1px solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:1290px;
    height:696px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
div#memory_board > div{
    background:url(MemoryCardFrontSmall.png) no-repeat;
    border:#FFF 2px solid;
    border-radius:12px;
    width:196px;
    height:156px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0px 14px 14px 0px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    font-size:64px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


</style>

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

// Scripted By Adam Khoury in connection with the following video tutorial: 
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_ohDPWmsM0


var memory_array = ['1.png','1.png','2.png','2.png','3.png','3.png','4.png','4.png','5.png','5.png','6.png','6.png','7.png','7.png','8.png','8.png','8.png','8.png','9.png','9.png','10.png','10.png','11.png','11.png','12.png','12.png'];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;
Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function(){
    var i = this.length, j, temp;
    while(--i > 0){
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        temp = this[j];
        this[j] = this[i];
        this[i] = temp;
    }
}
function newBoard(){
    tiles_flipped = 0;
    var output = '';
    Clicks = -1;
    memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
    for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++){
        output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_array[i]+'\')"></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
}
function memoryFlipTile(tile,val){
    if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2){
        tile.style.background = '#FFF';
        tile.style.border = '2px solid #000';
        tile.innerHTML = '<img src="'+val+'" />';
        if(memory_values.length == 0){
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        } else if(memory_values.length == 1){
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
            if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]){
                var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
                var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
                $(tile_1).css({transform: "scale(1.3) rotate(360deg)"});
                $(tile_2).css({transform: "scale(1.3) rotate(360deg)"});
                tiles_flipped += 2;
                // Clear both arrays
                memory_values = [];
                memory_tile_ids = [];
                // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
                if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length){
                    if(Clicks < 90) { 
                        alert("Wow! Only " + Clicks + " clicks!};
                    else {
                        alert("Let's try that again. See if you can complete the game in less than " + Clicks + " clicks.");
                    }
                    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                    newBoard();
                }
            } 
            else {
                function flip2Back(){
                    // Flip the 2 tiles back over
                    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
                    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
                    tile_1.style.background = 'url(MemoryCardFrontSmall.png) no-repeat';
                    tile_1.style.border = '2px solid #FFF';
                    tile_1.innerHTML = "";
                    tile_2.style.background = 'url(MemoryCardFrontSmall.png) no-repeat';
                    tile_2.style.border = '2px solid #FFF';
                    tile_2.innerHTML = "";
                    // Clear both arrays
                    memory_values = [];
                    memory_tile_ids = [];
                }
                setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>ADE Memory Game</h1>
    <p>Click or touch the squares to match the cards.</p>
</div>
<div id="memory_board">
</div>

<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<script>

    //Create a new gameboard
    newBoard();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate your CSS changes.

  - Use the `duration` argument to make the animation take 500ms each time.
  - Use the `complete` argument to animate to reverse the animation after it's completed.

So like

```
$(tile_1).animate({
  transform: "scale(1.3) rotate(360deg)"
}, 500, function() {
  $(this).animate({
    transform: "scale(1.0) rotate(0deg)"
  }, 500);
});
```

for `tile_1`.  Use similar code (or better, a function that takes the tile to animate as a parameter) for `tile_2` or any other tiles you want to animate.

Comment: You'd end up with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/63j5pzf5/
Note you have a couple other typos (i.e. near one of your `alert(...)` statements. You'll find it in the console when you run.

Comment: So, I put in that code for tile_1, but no animation occurs at all. It's as if the page is reading both animations and applying both at the same time, which results in them cancelling each other out. Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: This code snippet that you put in your answer looks like it should work, but for some reason, when I try the jfiddle and also on my live version, no animations occur. Even when I remove the callback function and just try to animate the first sequence of scale and rotation, nothing happens. The other function that I had with $(tile_1).css.... will do the first animation, but not the callback function. What could be interfering with the jquery animate do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure if `animate` works with `transform`. Short of that, you could `setTimeout` for the reverse transformation using CSS. `$(tile_1).css(...); setTimeout(function(){$(tile_1).css(...reverse...);}, 500)`

Comment: Yes! arcyqwerty - you nailed it with the setTimeout(function( )... That works! Thank you for the awesomeness!